# How to activate root using the Single-User Mode in Catalina

Tags: mac, catalina, root

I can't activate root using the Single-User mode since the Catalina update got released...

```
$ /sbin/mount -uw / 
$ launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist 
$ passwd
     Enter password : root
     Repeat password : root
passwd: Authentication server failed to complete the requested operation.
Authentication server failed to complete the requested operation.
$
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the slightly different volume scheme in Catalina - compared to pre-Cataline systems - you have to mount /System/Volumes/Data to prevent the read-only mount point /:

```
/sbin/mount -uw /System/Volumes/Data
```

Then the usual commands:

```
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist
passwd root
```

and enter the password.

On T2-chip Macs you have to boot to Recovery Mode and use dscl to enable root:

```
dscl -f /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD\ -\ Data/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default localhost -passwd /Local/Default/Users/root
```

If your main volume has another name than *Macintosh HD*, replace Macintosh\ HD with this name (e.g SystemCat):

```
dscl -f /Volumes/SystemCat\ -\ Data/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default localhost -passwd /Local/Default/Users/root
```