# Crash when trying to activate root in single user mode

Tags: macos, root, single-user

when i try to activate root in the single user mode, my computer crashes. It says something with stress and I have to press a key to restart.
I used the tutorial [How to activate root using the Single-User Mode in Catalina](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372642/how-to-activate-root-using-the-single-user-mode-in-catalina#).

I don’t want to reinstall macOS on top of my system.

What else can I try?

Comment: Do you want to reinstall the os? If not, you might have to document a bit more what you see or how you want to rocked. Also, you probably don’t need to activate root to do anything. On Catalina there are much better ways to gain control since root  is locked out of many many things at this point

Comment: Here is a video of what I see. https://gofile.io/?c=c0g3sK

Comment: @bmike (I don't want to reinstall the os)

Comment: The video doesn't help because it doesn't show what you *did* to get there.  That said, this sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  What problem are you trying to solve that you believe enabling the root user will solve?

Comment: Hello, to get there I used https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372642/how-to-activate-root-using-the-single-user-mode-in-catalina#. I am trying to get an admin access.